# React Materialize Parallax image is not scrolling with background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, materialize

I am trying to use a parallax from react-materiallize for a portfolio site. I've got the images working in the parallax however it doesn't not seem to be scrolling.

I've loaded JQuery before material CSS in the `index.html` file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Parallax, Row} from 'react-materialize'



export default class ParalaxComponent extends Component {

  render(){
    debugger
    return (
      <Row>
        <Parallax imageSrc="https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/DF3Q0T5_0O5CmGBTCWCBTcyGgmw=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/JavaScript-58acbb8a3df78c345bad32c2.jpg"></Parallax>
      </Row>
     )
  }
}
```

The image shows up but the animation is not being triggered thank you for your help.

Here is the app on [github](https://github.com/harryFBloch/portfolio) if that's an easier way to debug the issue.

Comment: A quick demo would be helpful here. Any console errors?

Comment: https://github.com/harryFBloch/portfolio

Comment: i pushed it up to github im not sure how else to give you a quick demo not getting any console errors

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using 'npm react-parallax' instead.
There is great documentation and a demo app [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-parallax)

Comment: Why to use a npm module for all those small things, first you moved from materialize-CSS to react-materialize (react-Materialize got materialize-css as dependency in its `package.json`). So indirectly you were using materialize-CSS. Now you're using react-parallax, only for a parallax, if you want then this could be done using materialize-CSS only, why to use too many npm modules and make your app slow. Check this - https://github.com/GermaVinsmoke/Reactize?files=1

Comment: I used react-parallax because the react-materialize parallax was not working for me, and I could not find a solution. I am using materialize for the rest of the styling of the app.